# How to raise an int in a string in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, int

I am making a storybook and, because I'm not very creative with names, I gave images page numbers like so.

```
ImageIcon pg1icon = new ImageIcon("images/1.png");
ImageIcon pg2icon = new ImageIcon("images/2.png");
ImageIcon pg3icon = new ImageIcon("images/3.png");

JLabel pg1Label = new JLabel(pg1icon);
JLabel pg2Label = new JLabel(pg2icon);
JLabel pg3Label = new JLabel(pg3icon);
```

Because I have 30 pages, this process is getting tedious.  Is there a way to scale the page num similar to i++?

Comment: You can use an array instead of individual variables.

Answer (score 3):

Using streams we can handle this requirement concisely as:

```
List<JLabel> labels = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 30)
    .mapToObj(i -> new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/" + i + ".png")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only need the `ImageIcon` for the `JLabel`, you could use one array to store your thirty `JLabel`(s). Like,

```
int pageCount = 30;
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[pageCount];
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) { // <-- i++ as requested
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(String.format("images/%d.png", 1+i));
    labels[i] = new JLabel(icon);
}
```

And then use `labels[0]` - `labels[29]` instead of `pg1Label` - `pg30Label`.

Comment: In the question, the image numbers start at 1, not 0.

Comment: @Andreas Right you are. Thanks!